# Magento 2.3.2 Import only images for multiple products

Tags: import, magento2

I want to import images for multiple products. I read many questions and I tried the answer but with no luck.

I want to import images from external server. For that I created CSV with `sku, base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image` column.

The value in all field is like :
htts://external.com/imgae_name

I selected "Product" in Entity Type, Import Behaviour is Add/ Update. I skip Image file directory.

When I click on "check data" button I am getting following error.

> Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 1

If I add Product type column then I am getting attribute set error. Can anybody help me on that ?

Even when I import custom attribute I am getting same error. For that I created csv with sku and cost.

Here cost is my product attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your Product type as = 'Default' that should stop the error when you click 'check data' when uploading your csv.